# MS SQL Server sum of sum fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql statement that will give me two columns from two tables using sub query.

```
select 
    sum(field1) as f1_sum,
    (select sum(field2) from table2) as f2_sum
from
    table1
group by
    table1.field_x
```

I want to get the total of `f1_sum + f2_sum` as the third column output from this query. It seems simple but I can't find a way around this.Question is how to get the sum of sum fields.

I am ok to write SP or a view to do this etc..

Can someone assist please  ?

Comment: You can use subquery

Answer (score 1):

you can use subquery like:

```
SELECT t1.f1_sum+t1.f2_sum AS total_sum FROM 
    (select sum(field1) as f1_sum , (select sum(field2) from table2) as f2_sum 
       from table1
     group by table1.field_x) AS t1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing it like this:

```
select t1.f1_sum, t2.f2_sum, coalesce(t1.f1_sum, 0) + coalesce(t2.f2_sum, 0)
from (select sum(field1) as f1_sum
      from table1 t1
      group by t1.field_x
     ) t1 cross join
     (select sum(field2) as f2_sum from table2) t2;
```

When possible, I prefer to keep table references in the `from` clause.  I added the `coalesce()` just in case any of the values could be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this :

```
SELECT SUM(a.field1) f1_sum, 
       SUM(b.field2) f2_sum,
       (SUM(a.field1) + SUM(b.field2)) f3_sum
from table1 a, table2 b
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can write,

```
select sum(field1) as f1_sum
       , (select sum(field2) from table2) as f2_sum
       , (ISNULL(sum(field1),0) + ISNULL((select sum(field2) from table2),0)) AS Total_Sum
from table1
group by table1.field_x
```